# How to sort nested array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

Mongo playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/BGtxQEBAvZh

I have an array field "opcoes", which I want to sort by date `dt`. Currently it is unsorted, e.g.

```
{
    "_id" : "w900c9b5a-666f-4857-92da-0b9c273dca40",
    "opcoes" : [
        {
            "dt" : ISODate("2021-11-16T11:17:55.386-03:00"),
            "text" : "2"
        },
        {
            "dt" : ISODate("2021-11-16T11:17:29.709-03:00"),
            "text" : "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

The expected result is:

```
{
    "_id" : "w900c9b5a-666f-4857-92da-0b9c273dca40",
    "opcoes" : [
        {
            "dt" : ISODate("2021-11-16T11:17:29.709-03:00") ,
            "text" : "3"
        },
        {
            "dt" : , ISODate("2021-11-16T11:17:55.386-03:00")
            "text" : "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can you help me? I was trying to use [`$SortArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) but it doesn't recognize it. I get " Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unknown expression $sortArray ".

I created the array using `$push`:

```
{ 
    $group: { 
        _id: "$chat_key", 
        opcoes: { 
            $push: { 
                text: "$text", 
                dt: "$dt" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Is there an option to sort inside a `$push`?

Thank you

Comment: Would be helpful if we can have the sample data and output in json document format instead of tabular format

Comment: I used tabular format because it is easier to explain I think. Just think of the columns as the fields in a json format. The "bot_msg" field has an array inside it.

Comment: No, we need json documents to reproduce the issue in tools like [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/)

Comment: The question is not clear, if you select 1, how do 3,7 come in the expected result use mongo playground as @ray said, and post the sample documents and expected result

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. I will reformulate the question as you asked

Comment: I reformulated the question as you asked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$sortArray` is for mongoDB [version 5.2](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) and higher, if you get this error, you are probably using an older version.

The best approach regardless of your version) is to to `$sort` before the `$push`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {dt: 1}
  },
  {
    $group: { 
    _id: "$chat_key", 
    opcoes: {$push: {text: "$text", dt: "$dt"}} 
  }
])
```

If you already have an array (and you can't control the pushing operation), and your version is older than 5.2, you can `$unwind`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$opcoes"
  },
  {
    $sort: {dt: 1}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      opcoes: {
        $push: {dt: "$opcoes.dt", text: "$opcoes.text"}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TI6ihOfaVlA)

Comment: Perfect, after I finished writing the question I ended up coming up with the same solution, but I mainted the question for future programmers reference. Good job.